# TikZ: How to set a node on an exact position on a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

to set a node on a line the usual way should be something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % place nodes
    \node[draw] at (0, 0)   (a) {A};
    \node[draw] at (5, 0)   (b) {B};

    \node[draw] at (0, -2)  (c)     {C};
    \node[draw] at (5, -2)  (d)     {D};

    % draw edges
    \draw[] (a) -- (b)  node[near start, above] {$x(kT)$};
    \draw[] (c) -- (d)  node[near start, above] {$y(kT)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But here i find it a little bit annoying, that the position of the node depends on the length of the line (what i try to illustrate in the above example). What i want is, that the nodes are exactly on the same position. To achieve this i have to write this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % place nodes
    \node[draw] at (0, -4)  (a2)    {A};
    \node[draw] at (3, -4)  (b2)    {B};

    \node[draw] at (0, -6)  (c2)    {C};
    \node[draw] at (5, -6)  (d2)    {D};

    % draw edges  
    \draw[] (a2.east)   -- (b2) node[at start, above right] {$x(kT)$};
    \draw[] (c2.east)   -- (d2) node[at start, above right] {$y(kT)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So my question is, is there a more intuitive way to do such things (something like the `near start`/`at start` node option)?

Comment: Like the `pos=##` key for `##` between [0,1]?

Comment: a little shorter: `\draw[] (a2.east) node[above right] {$x(kT)$}  -- (b2);`

Comment: Have a look at the section "Coordinate Calculations" in the TikZ manual.

Comment: Ok sorry, i think i did not state this. I do not want calculate this for every node. The `pos=##` key is only a more variable position statement. The bahaviour is like the `near start`/`midway` key isn't it? Further I do not find an overall key in the coordinate calculation section. So i think the shortest solution is what @someonr suggested.

Comment: The keys `at start`, `near start` and `midway` are just wrappers for `pos` (`0`, `.25` and `.5` respectively). All will depend on the length of the line and the position of the nodes (as well as their shape), if you count `0` times length as dependent of the length. If you just want to place a node at the `.east` anchor of the `a2` nodes you can do this as @someonr showed, with the `label` option or even without the line (`\node at (a2.east)`). Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve here? What should an “overall key” be? `place it like I want it`?

Comment: The `pos` key works only for nodes along a (sub)path. If you only want to place a node you can do this with `\path (<position>) node …{};` or shorter with `\node at (<position>{};`. You don’t need a path for that. If you want to place a node at a specific distance between nodes/coordinates, you will need either `calc` with the `!` syntax or use a lower-level PGF macro (implementing this in TikZ can probably done).

Answer (score 32):

Maybe this is too simplistic or not automatic enough for what you're really seeking, but I think based on the question text and comments that a simple `xshift=<shift-dimension>` will do. You can (optionally) wrap it into a style (here, `near start abs`) so the distance can be adjusted globally if needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{near start abs/.style={xshift=1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % place nodes
    \node[draw] at (0, 0)   (a) {A};
    \node[draw] at (3, 0)   (b) {B};

    \node[draw] at (0, -2)  (c)     {C};
    \node[draw] at (5, -2)  (d)     {D};

    % draw edges
    \draw[] (a) node[above,xshift=1cm] {$x(kT)$} -- (b);
    \draw[] (c) node[above,xshift=1cm] {$y(kT)$} -- (d);
    \draw (0,-3) node[above,near start abs] {Test} -- ++(7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]